# $http error callback does not work in combination with httpProvider responseInterceptor

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, callback

I added in my application a "loading screen". As found in this post: '[Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088924/is-it-possible-to-know-that-request-is-processing/19089022#19089022)'

Now I have the problem that all $http request results in the "success" callback. Even when the url does not exist.

```
$http.post("this doesnt even exist", { })
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("success"); //this callback is called
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("error"); //never called
});
```

When I disable the 'responseInterceptor' everything works fine. (exception, not found, wrong parameters -> all results in error callback)

I'm using a .NET Webservice to get my data from.

The values of parameters in success callback

```
data: ''
status: 0
headers: 'function(name) { ... }'
config: JSON.stringify(config)  '{"method":"POST","url":"this doesnt even exist","data":{}}'
```

Comment: I'm using 'AngularJS v1.0.8' (lastest stable version)

Comment: please provide code of the HttpInterceptor

Comment: @tschiela the code of HttpInterceptor is an exact copy as provider in the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the response interceptor you linked to "swallows" the error.

In the following code:

`return promise.then(hide, hide);`

The first `hide` is for the success callback, while the second is for the error callback.

The `hide` function itself just ends with `return r;` in all cases, which means it will return the response.

For your `$http.post` to know there was an error the response interceptor needs to return the promise as rejected instead: `return $q.reject(reason);`

Something along these lines should hopefully work or at least give further guidance (note that I have not been able to test it):

```
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(function ($q) {
        return function (promise) {
            numLoadings++;
            loadingScreen.show();

            var hide = function () {
                if (!(--numLoadings)) loadingScreen.hide();
            };

            var success = function (response) {
                hide();
                return response;
            };

            var error = function (reason) {
                hide();
                return $q.reject(reason);
            };

            return promise.then(success, error);
        };
    });
```